# Remove item from listview and add deleted item on the another listview activity?

Tags: android, android-listview

Can you give me an example of passing data from `ListView` to another ListView.

For example I have my `MainActivity.java` that has `ListView` and when i delete item on it. i want to achieve is to pass and add it to another `ListView` activity.

## MainActivity.java | OnitemClick

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    String member_name = rowItems.get(position).getMember_name();
    int product_icons = rowItems.get(position).getProfile_pic_id();
    String status = rowItems.get(position).getStatus();

    // passing data
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CarActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("member_name", member_name);
    i.putExtra("product_icons", product_icons);
    i.putExtra("status", status);

    RowItem item = rowItems.get(position);

    rowItems.remove(item);

    newadapter = new CustomAdapter(this, rowItems);
    mylistview.setAdapter(newadapter);

    newadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(),
            "Added to Cart: " + member_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

## CartActivity.java   | onCreate

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String member_names = extras.getString("member_name");
        int product_icons = extras.getInt("product_icons");
        String status = extras.getString("status");
    }

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem_cart>();

    RowItem_cart item = new RowItem_cart(member_names, product_icons, status);
    rowItems.add(item);

    mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    mylistview.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    //
    final CustomerAdapter_Cart adapter = new CustomerAdapter_Cart(this,
            rowItems);
    mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);

    mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    mylistview.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);

    mylistview.invalidateViews();
```

## CustomAdapter_cart

```
public class CustomerAdapter_Cart extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<RowItem_cart> rowItems;

public CustomerAdapter_Cart(Context context, List<RowItem_cart> rowItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;

}

public CustomerAdapter_Cart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

/* private view holder class */
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView product_icons;
    TextView member_name;
    TextView status;
    Button addtocart;
    EditText txtQuantity;
    TextView lblQty;
}

ViewHolder holder = null;

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_cart, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        holder.product_icons = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.product_icons);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        holder.addtocart = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnaddtocart);

        holder.txtQuantity = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity);

        holder.lblQty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblQty);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }
    RowItem_cart row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

    holder.product_icons.setImageResource(row_pos.getProfile_pic_id());
    holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getMember_name());
    holder.status.setText(row_pos.getStatus());
    holder.addtocart.setText(" add to cart");

    return convertView;
    }

  }
```

## RowItem_cart

```
public class RowItem_cart {

private String member_name;
private int profile_pic_id;
private String status;

public RowItem_cart(String member_name, int profile_pic_id, String status) {

    this.member_name = member_name;
    this.profile_pic_id = profile_pic_id;
    this.status = status;

}

public String getMember_name() {
    return member_name;
}

public void setMember_name(String member_name) {
    this.member_name = member_name;
}

public int getProfile_pic_id() {
    return profile_pic_id;
}

public void setProfile_pic_id(int profile_pic_id) {
    this.profile_pic_id = profile_pic_id;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

  }
```

Comment: put something you tried.

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainActivity` you probably have an `onItemSelected()` listener.  In there you can get the item that was removed from the active item list.  Assuming you have a field for the deleted items list you would simply call `add()` on that list with the item you just deleted.

Without some of your actual code that's about as far as we're going to be able to take you ;)

Comment: take note that my product_icons is a image